# How can I change the input sound source for video on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, audio

When recording video on my iPad I want to use internal music as the sound source, not the microphone. In other words, I want to play music on iPad, such as by playing a sound file and I want that played music to be the audio input for the video, not the microphone.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

### Disable Microphone for screen recording

You simply need to disable microphone for screen recording via control center.

1. Check in **Settings > Control Center** that the "Screen Recording" option has a "-" sign next to it (meaning that it is added and that it proposes to remove it).

Here, it won't be in the Control Center :

[image]

Here, it will :

[image]

2. Open **control center** by *swiping* downwards from the top-right-corner of your screen.
3. *Long-press* on the circle with a dot in the center to see the **Screen Recording options**.

[image]

4. Click on "**Microphone**" so it's disabled (grey)

[image]
(Here it's enabled)

This works for me, it will disable the microphone for screen recording and therefore use the iPad's sound.

---

### Combine video took from iPad's camera and sound (not from video)

This is how to take a video from the iPad camera and add custom sound to it.

There is no way *from the iPad itself* (without external devices) to do this.

I suggest you use [iMovie](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/imovie/id377298193?amp%3Bv0=www-us-ios-imovie-app-imovie), it is a built-in app (free) made by Apple. You have to :

([Download](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/imovie/id377298193?amp%3Bv0=www-us-ios-imovie-app-imovie) it if not already present (that would be weird) or is deleted)

1. Open **iMovie**
2. Create a project by clicking on "Movie".

[image]

3. Then, go to "Videos" and select the one.s on which you want to add sound.
4. Then, click on "**Create Movie**"

[image]

5. It should show the movie with the video.s added to it. Now, to remove the sound of the original video, click on the video and click on "**Detach audio**", than you can delete the detached audio by pressing on the audio and clicking on "Delete".

[image]

6. Now that the audio from the original video is deleted you can either **record some sound** (voice, etc.) with the microphone button or **import some sound** (from Files, pre-made iMovie sounds and Apple Music / iTunes) by clicking on Audio and selecting "My Music" to use Files and Apple Music / iTunes, "Sound Effects" and "Soundtracks" to use pre-made iMovie sounds.

[image]

Once you're happy with the result, to export to Photos, click on "Done", then click on the "Share" button (square with arrow pointing up) and click on "Save Video". If you want to save it anywhere you like, repeat the steps above but select another option than "Save Video".

Comment: My controls look different from yours. There is no circle icon and the bank of 4x4 icons at the bottom is not present. At my bottom I only have 4 buttons: a bell, stage manager, notes and camera.

Comment: @StaleHandle Oh, that's weird, I added some screenshots of the Control Center settings as it is for me. Check if it's the same for you. (It's as an edit to the answer)

Comment: Ok, I see I needed to add this control to the popup area. So, you are saying if I turn microphone off for "screen recording", then when I use the camera, it should revert to internal sound as the sound source even though I am using the camera and not screen recording?

Comment: @StaleHandle No, not camera, only Screen Recording.

Comment: @StaleHandle I edited my post and added how to add sound to a video took with camera. :)